# PCSoft Webdev 22 : Deployment error, server is looping

Tags: mysql, linux, web-deployment, windev

I'm working on a linux deployment project of an webdev's application.
This application is perfectly working on Windows.
But when I'm deploying it with the pcsoft's deployment tool on a linux server (PCSoft WebApplication Server), the server is looping, and I got a timeout message.

In the application, there is a screen where the user fill a form, to initialize the database's connection. When the user sends this form the server try to call the MySQL server, and it's at this moment, the server is looping.

And I don't have any log.

Can you help me ?

Comment: What error herrorinfo returns?

Comment: Nothing, just looping